# Remove text from RSS description that is not within a tag element

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, rss

I'm looking to remove text from an RSS description that is not within a tag element (ie. strong, p, span, etc.) I was able to remove a strong element, but I'm unable to target the "Location" text as it is not within a tag.

To clarify, I'm trying to remove

```
21.671N 158.117W or 5 nautical miles N of search location of 21.5928N 158.1034W.
```

I can't target a string because it will be different for each feed. Also, I tried applying a span tag to any text with no luck.

Below is my code...

```
<?php
  $rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/rss/ndbc_obs_search.php?lat=21.5928&lon=-158.1034&radius=100');

  $i = 0;
  foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";
    echo '<h2><a style="font-size:12px; text-decoration:none;" href="'. $item-      >link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h2>";
    $i++;
    if ($i >= 1){
      break;
    }
  }
?>
<script>
  document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[1].setAttribute("hidden", true);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this feed always has the 'location' item as the second line; you could split on `<br />`, remove the second line, then join back together with `<br />` again.

e.g.

```
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
  // Split on <br />
  $descriptionBits = explode("<br />", $item->description);
  // Remove the location line
  unset($descriptionBits[1]);
  // Glue the bits back together again
  $descriptionString = implode("<br />", $descriptionBits);

  // Then print it out
  echo "<p>" . $descriptionString . "</p>";
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the simple solution and clear comments.